# In a bar plot: For many observations the x axis is not readable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have 279 observations, I would like to plot them in a bar plot. the x axis values are the names of the observations and y axis are Deltas: numbers. The problem is the names are not readable. Is there a way to plot 279 on one plot where I can read the x axis for this huge number of observations.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 20))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
y_pos = np.arange(len(Names))
plt.xticks(y_pos, Names, color='white', rotation=45, fontweight='bold', fontsize='17',horizontalalignment='right')
ax.bar(Names,Deltas)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe only show a subset of the ticks? As in `plt.xticks(y_pos[::20], Names[::20], ...)`?

Comment: First we'd need a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Second, how do you imagine this would work? You can decrease the font, so that the labels aren't overlapping, but will they be readable then?

Comment: Plot a horizontal bar, make the figure larger, and put the labels at 0 or 90 (whichever one makes them flat on the axis).